# mod_rewrite in .htaccess and basic auth in vhost - access to paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

I want to lock down a website (made on Drupal) with basic auth. Drupal is using mod_rewrite in its .htaccess file. The problem I'm facing is this - my virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.mydomain.com:443>
        ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/http/stage/mywebsite/public_html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /srv/http/stage/mywebsite/public_html>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Basic Authentication"
                AuthUserFile "/srv/http/stage/mywebsite/.htpasswd"

                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                require valid-user
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This setup works for locking a website, but when I log in, I cannot access any paths like: https://subdomain.mydomain.com/content/aliquam-facilisi , because they give me: "Forbidden" error. How should config looks like to lock a website, but make it fully functional after logging in?

Apache version: 2.4.7

Edit: Added missing directive.

Comment: Does apache log anything in the error_log? And are you sure the .htaccess in your Drupal webroot will work when you set `AllowOverride None` in the root directory and don't override it for your DocumentRoot? Because really it shouldn't.

Comment: Oh sorry, `AllowOverride All` is there of course, I must have cut it out accidentally when I was formatting this configuration. It is there and problem exists with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out eventually. In apache2 error logs there was an information:

> ... cannot read directory for multi ...

I figured that it needs to have something to do with "MultiViews" option, so I disabled this option in my virtual host. Then everything started to work.